# How to add a gap between ExpansionPanelList in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

In flutter, I am trying to create an ExpansionPanelList and I want to add space between the expansion tiles. Can anyone help me with this

Here's the code I've used:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
            children: items
                .map(
                  (e) => ExpansionPanelRadio(
                      canTapOnHeader: true,
                      value: e.header,
                      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              e.header,
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                      body: ListTile(
                        title:
                            Text(e.body, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      )),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


class Item {
  final String header;
  final String body;

  Item({
    required this.header,
    required this.body,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExpansionTile` inside the `ListView` instead of `ExpansionPanelList` widget.

Full example:

```dart
main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Item> items = List.generate(
        5, (index) => Item(header: 'header$index', body: 'body$index'));

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: _buildTiles(items[index]),
      ),
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Item item) {
    return Card(
      child: ExpansionTile(
        key: ValueKey(item),
        title: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item.header,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text(item.body, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final String header;
  final String body;

  Item({
    required this.header,
    required this.body,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Actually, you can't. When expansion list is folded, you can't set space betweeen `ExpansionPanelRadio`. There are limited parameters in `ExpansionPanelRadio` and there is no margin parameter in it.
2. Also, you can't wrap your `ExpansionPanelRadio` in `Padding` because `ExpansionPanelList.radio children` must be `List<ExpansionPanelRadio>`.
   So, I don't recommend customizing it. It takes a lot of effort.

What I recommend is using https://pub.dev/packages/accordion plugin. It gives you full control of your Expansion List and it's easy to use.

Here's what it looks like when using this plugin:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GotJimmy/accordion/master/assets/accordion_demo.gif

**Have Fun TT**

Answer (score 0):

(1) Wrap the ExpansionPanleRadio within padding and put only bottom padding.

(2) check that may be it has margin property.